# nvidia-settings shows no content in its window

Tags: nvidia, nvidia-geforce

can anybody help please?

Kubuntu 20.04. GE Force gtx1050ti. Installed Nividia Server 450, from repository using Muon.

When invoking 'nvidia-settings' the nvidia window appears but has no content!

Output from terminal shows...

(process:18974): Gtk-WARNING **: 08:23:46.948: Locale not supported by C library.
Using the fallback 'C' locale.

ERROR: NVIDIA driver is not loaded

ERROR: Unable to load info from any available system

(nvidia-settings:18974): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 08:23:47.413: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
** Message: 08:23:47.420: PRIME: No offloading required. Abort
** Message: 08:23:47.420: PRIME: is it supported? no

Answer (score 0):

The 450 driver is definitely a problem. Resolved the problem by installing the 390 driver package. Voila, card and nvidia-settings are working for me.